# Python Script Working in Jupyter But Not Command Line, listdir error

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook, shutil, listdir

I have a Python script where if the hash is available (checks against a csv full of hashes and file paths, then adds columns to the data frame), then I want to move a file to a new location.

I'm getting an issue in my script where my path is coming out as a float, when it should be a string. In my jupyter notebook, when I do `print(type(path))` the output is `<class 'str'>` but when I do `print(type(path))` in my script when I run it on the command line, it returns `<class 'float'>`.

When I run the full script, I get the error below:

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare_hashes_to_image_hashes.py", line 82, in <module>
    for source_filename in os.listdir(path):
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike, integer or None, not float
```

Why is it working in my jupyter notebook, but not in my script?

**Script (sections relevant to issue)**

```
#!/usr/bin/python36

import os
import shutil

# make columns into lists
users = list(master_df['USER_JID'])
avails = list(master_df['HASH_AVAILABLE'])
paths = list(df_merged['FILE_PATH'])
hashes = list(df_merged['SHA1_BASE16'])

# define source location and destination location
destination = "/opt/PhotoTips/input/"
source_img = "/opt/PhotoTips/hash_images/"

"""
Move images to appropriate user img folders
"""

# for every value in available list
for i in range(len(avails)):
    # each value in user list is a user
    user = users[i]
    # each value in path list is a path
    path = paths[i]
    # each value in hash value list is a hash
    hash_val = hashes[i]
    # build full location
    location = destination + user + '/img'
    # if hash image is available
    if 'Available' in avails[i]:
        # debug purposes
        # print(type(path)) # returns <class 'float'>
        # suggested by marklap
        # if isinstance(path, float): 
            # print(path)
            # returns nan
        for source_filename in os.listdir(path):   <---- line with the issue
            # confirm text file for match
            if source_filename.startswith(hash_val):
                # build full path
                source_file_path = os.path.join(path, source_filename)
                # copy image to appropriate user location
                shutil.copy(source_file_path, location)
    # if hash image is NOT available
    else:
        # do nothing
        pass
```

Comment: What kind of clue do you get when you print the path value if it's a float? `print(path)  # when it's a float`

Comment: @marklap I just get `nan`. I've also edited my original post to include this.

Comment: My guess whatever method you're using to ingest the data is different in Jupyter than from the command line. I believe (I have no first hand experience though) that some Python and/or Jupyter packages will include SciPy/NumPy helpers that add some helpful "magic". Perhaps in Jupyter you're getting unsolicited help? In any case, standard Python won't automatically provide the same help.

Comment: can you try this `paths = list(df_merged['FILE_PATH'].astype('str'))`